# Employee "Registration Number"

Tags: terminology

I need to know what is the proper way to name the registration number of an employee within a company or firm to uniquely identify her/him. In my country (Italy) we we make large use of it. Thanks.

Edit: Companies use to assign a number or code to every new employee in order to uniquely identify her/him for administration purposes (e.g. the number that appears on the payroll). The badge ID would not work, as it is the ID assigned to the badge itself, not the employee, thus it can possibly change, and not every company uses badges anyway. What is English standard way to name such a code?

Comment: This is a question for Workplace.SE, not here.

Comment: expand a little. What is wrong with "Registration Number"? If you are looking for what is the best *business practice* then this question may be better for Workplace.SE.

Comment: I just have to translate an Italian term. "Registration Number" is just my best description for this term, but what I am looking for is the common name for such a "number" (that might also contain characters anyway), a name that everybody will immediately understand what it refers to.

Comment: If this is a legal term, there is probably an official EU English translation for it. I don't think there is any specific term in use in the U.S., since Social Security Numbers are commonly used to identify people uniquely. Large organizations almost certainly assign a unique internal code for their employees, but there's no commonality in terminology from organization to organization— it might be your *badge number* or your *team member ID* or your *associate ID code* and so on. Can you explain how this number is assigned and used?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belhttp://workplace.stackexchange.com/ongs on

Comment: Isn't this site about "English Language & Usage"? My question is about a precise Italian term to define a "unique internal code" (thanks @choster) an employee gets assigned at the beginning of the working relation with their employer and which they keep until they resign. Every employee gets this code regardless of their role, status, or position in the organization, so in Italy there exist a very precise and common name for it. I am looking for the corresponding English term. Sorry, I may have explained badly. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Employee ID - can be a number, a string of characters, a combination, whatever you prefer.

So yes, Employee ID. Or EID for short.
Or if you look for a more specific case, Employee ID number - IDN.